# How to deal with error code 101 for Spark-submit on Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, jar, spark-submit

I am trying to run the following code to submit a spark application to a kubernetes' cluster:

```
 /opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --master k8s://https://<spark-master-ip>:6443 --deploy-mode cluster --name spark-pi --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --conf spark.executor.instances=5 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=newfrontdocker/spark:v3.0.1-j14 local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.1.1.jar 100
```

When I try to run this code, the container runs temporarily before I end up getting this particular error message and the container terminates:

```
 container status:
                 container name: spark-kubernetes-driver
                 container image: newfrontdocker/spark:v3.0.1-j14
                 container state: terminated
                 container started at: 2021-07-17T11:49:46Z
                 container finished at: 2021-07-17T11:49:48Z
                 exit code: 101
                 termination reason: Error
21/07/17 06:49:13 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application status for spark-c15c11340f204794b51bf8d79397bf9e (phase: Failed)
21/07/17 06:49:13 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Container final statuses:


         container name: spark-kubernetes-driver
         container image: newfrontdocker/spark:v3.0.1-j14
         container state: terminated
         container started at: 2021-07-17T11:49:46Z
         container finished at: 2021-07-17T11:49:48Z
         exit code: 101
         termination reason: Error
21/07/17 06:49:13 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application spark-pi with submission ID default:spark-pi-4ed9627ab44c778d-driver finished
21/07/17 06:49:14 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
21/07/17 06:49:14 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-3d1a7ff3-1dc9-4db0-acfa-ed52706122b6
```

What is the exit code 101 and what do I need to do to fix this issue so I run spark apps on the kubernetes' cluster?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was that the jar path was incorrect.

I guess that the path should be:

```
local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.1.jar
```

(3.0.1 instead of 3.1.1), because you use `newfrontdocker/spark:v3.0.1-j14` image.